# Print headers hierarchy

Tags: c

I want to print headers hierarchy in some automated way. The goal is to preserve order in header files inclusion.

I have tried to do the following in header "tmp1.h":

```
#ifndef HIERARCHY_PRINTING
#define HIERARCHY_PRINTING "start: "
#endif 

#undef PREVIOUS_PRINTING
#define PREVIOUS_PRINTING HIERARCHY_PRINTING "->"
#undef HIERARCHY_PRINTING
#define HIERARCHY_PRINTING PREVIOUS_PRINTING "tmp1.h"

#ifndef _TMP1_
#define _TMP1_

// Some stuff

#endif

#undef PREVIOUS_PRINTING
#define PREVIOUS_PRINTING HIERARCHY_PRINTING ";"
#undef HIERARCHY_PRINTING
#define HIERARCHY_PRINTING PREVIOUS_PRINTING
```

And in "tmp.c":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tmp1.h"

const char *str = HIERARCHY_PRINTING;

int main() {
    printf("Headers hierarchy:\n");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
tmp.c:7:19: error: ‘HIERARCHY_PRINTING’ undeclared here (not in a function)
tmp.c:7:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before string constant
```

I expected to see something like:

```
start: ->tmp1.h;
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You have a circular reference in the macros you've written: `HIERARCHY_PRINTING` expands to `PREVIOUS_PRINTING`, which then expands to `HIERARCHY_PRINTING ";"`, etc etc. That said, the compiler errors I get when compiling this code are a little different, so it's possible that something was lost in translation when you simplified your example.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown What error did you get? Actually I didn't simplify anything since it is just an experiment.

Comment: You'll get better help if you post an example that exhibits the behavior you're asking about! Here's the code I compiled and the output from the compiler: http://lpaste.net/345138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you tried to save some intermediate result in `PREVIOUS_PRINTING` macro definition which should store the contents of macro `HIERARCHY_PRINTING` at that point to be used later, after `HIERARCHY_PRINTING` is undefined.

But such approach doesn't work since preprocessor doesn't unfold definitions  until they are needed. And `#undef` command just throws away what was defined before it. So for your example when preprocessor finishes handling of the header file it will have the following:

```
#define PREVIOUS_PRINTING HIERARCHY_PRINTING ";"
#define HIERARCHY_PRINTING PREVIOUS_PRINTING
```

So when it will try to unfold the value of `HIERARCHY_PRINTING` it will get `HIERARCHY_PRINTING ";"` and that it since recursion is prohibited. And finally the compiler will complain for the undeclared `HIERARCHY_PRINTING` since there no such declarations in the code.